# R loop assign output to new vector

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I am working in R trying to generate several distinct vectors using a for loop.

First I created a small reproducible example data frame called `df`.

```
cluster.assignment <- c("1 Unknown", "1 Unknown", "2 Neuron","3 
PBMC","4 Basket")
Value1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
Value2 <- c("191","234","178","929","123")
df <- data.frame(cluster.assignment,Value1,Value2)
```

df

```
  cluster.assignment Value1 Value2
1          1 Unknown      a    191
2          1 Unknown      b    234
3           2 Neuron      c    178
4             3 PBMC      d    929
5           4 Basket      e    123 .
```

Next I create a variable named `clusters` that includes keys to the datasets that I am interested in.

```
clusters <- c("1 ","4 ")
```

Here is my attempt to extract rownames of the data of interest in `df` using a for loop.

```
for (COI in clusters) { 
  name2 <- c(gsub(" ","", paste("Cluster", COI, sep = "_")))
  assign(Cluster_1, name2, envir = parent.frame())
  name2 <- grep(COI, df$cluster.assignment)
}
```

Desired output is two vectors called `Cluster_1` and `Cluster_4`.

`Cluster_1` would contain the values `1` and `2`

`Cluster_4` would contain the value `5`

I can't seem to figure out how to assign the name of the `COI` variable to  be the name of the output vector.

Comment: `COI` takes the value of each element of `clusters`, that is, first it is `"1 "` and then it is `"2 "`. A number with a space is an exceptionally bad variable name--is this really what you want, to assign the name of the COI variable to be the name of the output?

Comment: In this case yes because I am mining an existing dataset generated by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest against using `assign`. Instead, I'll create a named list. [See this answer for a long discussion of why lists are better than sequentially named variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061). If, at any point, you decide you want to convert the list to objects in the global environment, you can use `list2env`, but doing so will probably just make more work.

```
## subset the data to the parts we care about, use `split` to separate it
## into a list
subdf = df[grepl(paste(clusters, collapse = "|"), df$cluster.assignment), ]
result = split(subdf, subdf$cluster.assignment, drop = TRUE)
result
# $`1 Unknown`
#   cluster.assignment Value1 Value2
# 1          1 Unknown      a    191
# 2          1 Unknown      b    234
# 
# $`4 Basket`
#   cluster.assignment Value1 Value2
# 5           4 Basket      e    123

## name the list as desired
names(result) = paste("Cluster", trimws(clusters), sep = "_")
result
# $`Cluster_1`
#   cluster.assignment Value1 Value2
# 1          1 Unknown      a    191
# 2          1 Unknown      b    234
# 
# $Cluster_4
#   cluster.assignment Value1 Value2
# 5           4 Basket      e    123

## if only the row names are needed, use lapply
result = lapply(result, row.names)
result
# $`Cluster_1`
# [1] "1" "2"
# 
# $Cluster_4
# [1] "5"
```

A few other notes - I assume you are including the spaces in `clusters` to prevent, e.g., `"1"` from matching `"12 foo"`. You might consider using the regex word boundary `"\\b1\\b"` instead, as `"1 "` will still match, say, `"11 foo"` or `"21 bar"`. Better yet, you could use `strplit` or similar to create a new column with just the numeric key you want to match.

Comment: Oh my, I see now why the spaces are so bad.  Thanks for your suggestions and very informative answer I will give them a try!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the necessity to create a for loop for this unless you have your own reasons,  but the following code gives you what you want:

```
library(data.table)
Cluster_1<-df[df$cluster.assignment %like% "1 ", c("Value1", "Value2")]
Cluster_2<-df[df$cluster.assignment %like% "4 ", c("Value1", "Value2")]
View(Cluster_1);View(Cluster_2)
```

you can remove or alter c("Value1", "Value2") to get the columns that you want in the final output.

Comment: I should have specified that this is a small portable example. Unfortunately in real life I need to repeat this over hundreds of different COI values.  So a loop to iterate the process and make it portable across datasets is required.  The heart of the question really is how do we do this in a for loop or some other high throughput way.